# ReplaceAll doesn't replace all, factor out constants first

Tags: matrix, replacement

I have this matrix:

```
mat = {{{{0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{1}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0}, {0, 0, 0}},{{0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
    {{0}, {0, 0, 0}}}, 
  {{{-1}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
    {{0}, {0, 0, 0}}}, 
  {{{0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0}, {0, z, -y}}, 
    {{0}, {-z, 0, x}}}, 
  {{{0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0}, {0, -z, y}}, {{0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
    {{0}, {y, -x, 0}}}, 
  {{{0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0}, {2 z, 0, -2 x}}, {{0}, {-y, x, 0}}, 
    {{0}, {0, 0, 0}}}};
```

When I run `ReplaceAll` (/.) on it using these rules:

```
rules = {{{1}, {0, 0, 0}} -> X1, {{t}, {2 x3, 2 y3, 2 z3}} -> 
    X2, {{0}, {y, -x, 0}} -> X3, {{0}, {z, 0, -x}} -> 
    X4, {{0}, {0, z, -y}} -> X5, {{0}, {0, 0, 0}} -> 0};
```

it doesn't replace everything, but produces:

```
{{0, X1, 0, 0, 0}, {{{-1}, {0, 0, 0}}, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  X5, {{0}, {-z, 0, x}}}, {0, 0, {{0}, {0, -z, y}}, 0, X3}, {0, 
  0, {{0}, {2 z, 0, -2 x}}, {{0}, {-y, x, 0}}, 0}}
```

I expect this:

```
{{0, X1, 0, 0, 0}, {-X1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, X5, -X4}, {0, 0, -X5, 
  0, X3}, {0, 0, 2X4, -X3, 0}}
```

Is there an automated way of doing these replacements?

Comment: Post code, not images, please.

Comment: Can you please change your formatted tex into code that is useable & easily copy & pasted into Mathematica? While this certainly is visually appealing, there is no ability for others to easily help to answer this due to the lack of code that can be easily copy & pasted into a notebook.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions,
https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1614/handling-questions-and-associated-answers-when-question-is-fundamentally-changed

Comment: @ciao I've incorporated MichaelE2's code. How's it look now?

Answer (score 2):

Usually I look for algebraic ways to make algebraic transformations instead of replacements based on syntactic patterns. I couldn't figure out a purely algebraic given the unsymmetric structure of the matrix (`mat`). The function `propRule[x -> y]` constructs a hybrid algebraic/syntactic-pattern rule that replaces an expression, when it is proportional to a given expression `x`, by the product of the constant of proportionality and the replacement value `y`.

```
ClearAll[findProportionality, propRule];
findProportionality[v_, w_] := Replace[
   DeleteDuplicates@DeleteCases[
     Flatten@{Quiet[Check[Simplify[v/w], $Failed, {Thread::tdlen}]]},
     Indeterminate],
   {{r_?NumericQ} :> r, {} :> Indeterminate, _ :> $Failed}];

propRule[(Rule | RuleDelayed)[x_, y_]] := (* replace if proportional *)
 v_ :> With[{r = findProportionality[v, x]},
   r*y /; NumericQ[r]]

rules = {
   {{0}, {0, 0, 0}} -> 0,
   propRule[{{1}, {0, 0, 0}} -> X1],
   propRule[{{t}, {2 x3, 2 y3, 2 z3}} -> X2],
   propRule[{{0}, {y, -x, 0}} -> X3],
   propRule[{{0}, {z, 0, -x}} -> X4],
   propRule[{{0}, {0, z, -y}} -> X5]};

mat /. rules
(*
  {{   0,  X1,    0,   0,   0},
   { -X1,   0,    0,   0,   0},
   {   0,   0,    0,  X5, -X4},
   {   0,   0,  -X5,   0,  X3},
   {   0,   0, 2 X4, -X3,   0}}
*)
```

It also handles some odd things:

```
Sin[2 x] /. propRule[Sin[x] Cos[x] -> s]
(*  2 s  *)
```